# yarn install consumes all memory on TeamCity and Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, teamcity, yarnpkg

I'd really like to get yarn working with TeamCity or Jenkins, however
`yarn install` consumes all my build server's cpu & memory, even with
a tiny npm project. Any idea why?

### Summary

- `yarn install`, when run by TeamCity or Jenkins, consumes most CPU/memory, never finishes
- running `yarn install` from the command line on the build server works (finishes in a few seconds)
- `npm install` completes in a few seconds when run by TeamCity/Jenkins
- build server: Windows Server 2012, 2 cores, 4GB mem
- yarn version 1.6.0
- Jenkins version 2.107.2
- TeamCity version 2017.2.3
- Have tried Node.js versions 8.11.1 and 9.11.1

### Details

Steps:

Create a tiny npm project:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
yarn init  # all defaults
yarn add dummy-module  # tiny test package
```

Commit this to git, set up a Jenkins or TeamCity build with a single command `yarn install`.

The build never finishes, with the last line of console output: `yarn install v1.6.0`.
At this time, the Node.js process is consuming most of the CPU and memory on the
build machine. Changing the command to `npm install` makes it run successfully.

Since it's common to Jenkins and TeamCity, it seems like the problem is to do with
running sub processes from java. I can't find any indication of what's going wrong
in either the TeamCity or Jenkins logs. When aborting the Jenkins build,
I see the following in jenkins.err.log:

```
Apr 22, 2018 8:59:11 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: master-cake #9 aborted
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:324)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:155)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Comment: you need to isolate the CI server and build agents. OK.for your problem, you need to isolate the yarn process. the short way - docker. can you use docker on your server?

Comment: and try to pass `--max-old-space-size=2048`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor can't use docker unfortunately. I tried --max-old-space-size with a range of sizes, with same results as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left some crucial information out of the original question - I'm also using yarn's offline mirror, which was stored on a network drive. It turns out that the TeamCity windows service can't access network drives: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-AgentrunningasWindowsServiceLimitations

Relocating yarn's offline mirror to a local directory solved the issue for both TeamCity and Jenkins.