# yarn install and build consumes 100% CPU and memory 95%

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, yarnpkg

I am working on Electron, Angular 8, Nodejs based project. Whenever I use the following command, my system consumes 100% CPU utilization and 95% memory, and the system freezes for 5 to 7 minutes. I am using yarn instead of npm as suggested by our UI architects.

I use the following command.

```
yarn install && yarn build
```

I am using Windows 10 with 16 GB RAM. It is a common problem for other team members also.
As per `package.json`, the command for yarn build is

```
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js",
```

I provide below the code for `webpack.dev.js`

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
});
```

Currently, the size of `node_modules` directory is 1.5 GB.
I want to know whether it is the expected behavior in case NodeJS or yarn-based project? I have very large applications in java but when I build using Maven or Gradle, I do not see this kind of behavior.
Please suggest me whether it can be improved.

I have also gone through the following StackOverflow link and could not get a proper answer.
[yarn install consumes all memory on TeamCity and Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961323/yarn-install-consumes-all-memory-on-teamcity-and-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `webpack` problem. Have you run into [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/2321)?

The response boils down to this:

> What is happening under the hood: At this moment we use antwar, a
>   Static site generator created by one of the original contributors to
>   this repo, it uses Workers which use all availables cores in your
>   system, basically occupying the entire CPU capacity.

There is an option to limit cores, but the link is not working and I'm currently searching for it in the official webpack github.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have already gone through this link and it did not work. By the way the link is broken. https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/blob/master/antwar.config.js#L5